# How can I use jQuery to calculate the sum of a table column from a dynamically added row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop, sum

I have a scenario where someone can click a button and add a new entry to a receipt (a table). Every click of the button would add a new row, the first column being a product name and the second item value. So I would want to find the sum of the item value cells.

```
HTML

<div id="cartSection">
                <table id="tableCart">

                </table>
                <br>
                <div id="summary">
                    <p>Your total is: </p><p id="total123"></p>
                </div>
</div>



JAVASCRIPT

function populateCart(){
    
    var table = document.getElementById("tableCart");
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotalValue");
    var amount = document.getElementById("select3").value;
    var godzilla = "GODZILLA - GODZILLA VS. KONG - 2021 1OZ PURE GOLD COIN ";

    

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    row.className = "row1";
// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.className = "cartItem";

// Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML = amount.toString()+"x "+godzilla;
    cell2.innerHTML = subtotal.innerHTML;
    

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x, sum;
        var tableCart;
        $(".row1").each(function(){
            tableCart = $(this);
            x = tableCart.closest('.cartItem').val();
            sum += parseInt(x);
            
        });
        $("#total123").html(sum);
      });
}
```

I'm trying to  use jQuery to calculate the sum of the column, and after the sum is calculated change the innerHTML of some text underneath the table displaying the total. I'm trying to add the new cells created to the "cartItem" class so I can select them with jQuery. The text isn't changing, and I'm not sure why so if anyone could help out I greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: can you create a snippet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculate the sum of the column from dynamically created rows in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844804/calculate-the-sum-of-the-column-from-dynamically-created-rows-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the reduce function to get sum of (.cartItem) values

reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b))

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready` function you have defined only fires once when the document loads. As such, all your rows are totaled as soon as the document loads, but not every time a row is added. You can pull out the addition into a new function, then call that function once the values change in the cell. Something like:

```
function populateCart(){

  //If neither of these have an actual div in the DOM, they will throw an exception and the rest of the javascript will not process
  var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotalValue");
  var amount = document.getElementById("select3").value;

  ...
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.className = "cartItem";

  // Add some text to the new cells:
  cell1.innerHTML = amount.toString()+"x "+godzilla;
  cell2.innerHTML = subtotal.innerHTML;

  sumRows();

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    sumRows();
});

function sumRows() {
    var x, sum;
    var tableCart;
    $(".row1").each(function(){
        tableCart = $(this);
        x = tableCart.closest('tr').find('.cartItem').val();
        sum += parseInt(x);
        
    });
    $("#total123").text(sum);
}
```

Realistically, you would probably want to listen for a new row being added, and then call the sumRows() function to add the total again. Or keep a running total and when a new row is added, just add the value of that new row to the total.

EDIT:
Now that I see that is all the javascript is in a function itself, I have updated the code to work better for you. Be sure to note that instead of `$("#total123").html(sum);`, try using `$('#total123').text(sum)`. Also, notice that you are trying to get a `.value` of the `var amount` where the 'select3' id does not exist in the DOM. That will throw an error and cause the javascript not to complete.

Comment: I edited the OP but pretty much whenever a button is pressed, the populateCart() function gets called. I tried sticking an alert in there and it looked like it worked to me, if there's 3 rows added then I get 3 alerts. I tried your edits but it didn't work for me either :(

Comment: The text is displaying now, but it's NaN :(
Appreciate the help greatly, learning one step at a time lol

Comment: Great! NaN means it isn't a number, likely the parseInt(x) is trying to parse a value that isn't a number. If you add a `console.log(x)` then that will show you the value of x in the dev tools console, good for debugging. likely you want to get `x = tableCart.closest('tr').find('.cartItem').innerHtml();` to get the text of that cell, instead of `.val()` which should be used for text boxes instead of table cells . https://api.jquery.com/val/